# Can i create a view using join query in SQLALchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, join, view, sqlalchemy

Is there any possibilities to create a views by combining 2 tables in Alchemy:

```
class CreateView(Executable, ClauseElement):
    def __init__(self, name, select):
        self.name = name
        self.select = select


@compiles(CreateView)
def visit_create_view(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "CREATE VIEW %s AS %s" % (
         element.name,
         compiler.process(element.select, literal_binds=True)
         )


# Method to create view with top three articles
def view_top_three():
    top_three_view = CreateView('test', db.select([art.columns.title, func.count(log.columns.path)]) 
        .group_by(policies.columns.name, join_object.columns.policy_name) \

    # engine.execute(top_three_view)

    v = Table('popular', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    for r in engine.execute(v.select()):
        print(r)


def main():

    try:
        engine = db.create_engine(DATABASE_URI).execution_options(autocommit=True)
        connection = engine.connect()
    except:
        print('Error establishing DB connection')

    # Import metadata
    metadata = db.MetaData()

    # Import articles, authors and log tables
    art = db.Table('policies', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    aut = db.Table('join_object', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

    # Call the method which creates view and selects from view
    view_top_three()
```

Comment: Yes, infact it is done in the wiki example that the `CreateView` recipe comes from: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/Views

Comment: The is an error. I was wondering if it's possible to check this question
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811651/creating-a-view-while-joining-two-tables-in-alchemy).
And Thanks for helping  @IljaEverilä